# error in hibernate query

Tags: mysql, hibernate

my hibernate.cfg.xml is this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD   3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/****</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">***</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">*****</property>

<property name="hibernate.query.factory_class">org.hibernate.hql.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactor    y</property>
<property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
<property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
<property name="show_sql">false</property>
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
<!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
<!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
    <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

<mapping class="entities.MisurazioneOraria"/>
<mapping class=....
    ....>
<listener type="post-insert" class="MisurazioneOrariaInsertListener"/>

</session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

i try to do query from this line code that is the listener :

```
ArrayList<MisurazioneOraria> mis =  (ArrayList<MisurazioneOraria>)    session.createQuery("from (misurazione_oraria) where sensore_idsensore = :idsensore").setParameter("idsensore", m.getSensore().getIdSensore()).list();
```

and the error is that :

```
mag 27, 2012 6:30:33 PM org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener   performExecutions
Grave: Could not synchronize database state with session
org.hibernate.QueryException: in expected: misurazione_oraria [from (misurazione_oraria) where sensore_idsensore = :idsensore]
```

my mysql version is 5.5.23. thanks for the help.

Comment: i am seeing the space here 'org.hibernate.hql.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactor    y" can u check once..

Answer (score 1):

Your entity class is named `MisurazioneOraria`, not `misurazione_oraria`. HQL uses entities and fields/properties. It doesn't use table and column names.

Read the [HQL documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#queryhql).

Moreover, `Query.list()` returns a List, and not necessarily an ArrayList. You shouldn't cast the result of the query to ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

change it to

```
List<MisurazioneOraria> mis = session.createQuery("from MisurazioneOraria where idSensore = :idsensore").setParameter("idsensore", m.getSensore().getIdSensore()).list();
```